# Property of integral of product as one function approaches 0

Tags: calculus

**Edit** I apologise, I am more interested in the conditions that make this property true. In response to Gudson's example, would the result be true if the condition that $g(x)$ cannot depend on $c$ was added?

For a real valued integral where $\frac{f(xc)}{c}$ and $g(x)$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ for all $c > 0$: $$I = \int_{a}^{b} g(x)\cdot \frac{f(xc)}{c} \: \mathrm{d}x$$

Suppose $\frac{f(xc)}{c}\rightarrow0$ as $c\rightarrow\infty$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Does $I\rightarrow0$ as $c\rightarrow \infty$?

I'm trying to visualise this in terms of making the graph of $g(x)$ on $[a,b]$ smaller and smaller and this property seems to be intuitively true. Is there a more convincing way to show it (if it is true)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $c >0 $; let $[a,b] := [2,3]$; let $f: x \mapsto \log x :\ [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$; and let $g: x \mapsto c\log (cx) :\ [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $f, g$ satisfy the requirements but for all $x \in [a,b]$ we have
$$
g(x)\cdot \frac{f(cx)}{c} = c\log (cx) \cdot \frac{\log (cx)}{c} \to \infty
$$
as $c$ grows.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more interested in "how to make this result true", so would it be true if $g(x)$ was not allowed to depend on $c$?

Comment: No problem. A suggestion: Maybe you can try to put this point in your question to assume away any logically acceptable example like the present one but not interesting with respect to your purpose.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer and edited my post. Would deleting and re-asking the question be more adherent to community guidelines?

Comment: Though I am not sure, according to my experience here, re-posting a question without substantial difference may not be a good idea. This is for your reference. :)